# Ionic && Laravel connection

Tags: angularjs, api, ionic-framework, laravel-5

I built a Laravel 5.2 website and an Ionic app. Now I want my Ionic app to connect to Laravel.

I searched and found that I must check at my controller the request I got, if it is from Ionic I must return just a JSON response without any view. Otherwise I can return a view with anything I want.

Any suggestions?

```
  if(ionic request)return just json
  else 
  return view('home')->with(['users'=>$this->users]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
return json_encode($users);
```